# Echo raw XML into file with PowerShell - Quotes being removed

Tags: windows, powershell, system-administration

I am trying to have windows scheduled task (XML) files created via powershell with the following command:

```
$userName = $ENV:USERNAME
$compName = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME

echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-10-09T14:28:16</Date>
    <Author>$userName</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>


    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT2M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2014-10-09T14:28:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>$compName\$userName</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>//Nologo //B C:\Microsoft\Windows\Desktop\Initialize.vbs</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>" >> dog.xml
```

However the output file has lost all of it's quotes as seen below:

```
    <?xml version=
1.0 encoding=UTF-16?>
<Task version=1.2 xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task>
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-10-09T14:28:16</Date>
    <Author>Xaptoxa</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT2M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2014-10-09T14:28:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id=Author>
      <UserId>GIBSON\Xaptoxa</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context=Author>
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>//Nologo //B C:\Microsoft\Windows\Desktop\Initialize.vbs</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I've also tried using single quotes to nest but this results in the variables failing. Along with nesting I've also tried various Powershell techniques such as the Out-File CmdLet etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a here string instead. This worked for me (partial XML removed for space saving):

```
$userName = $ENV:USERNAME
$compName = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME

echo @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-10-09T14:28:16</Date>
    <Author>$userName</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
  ...
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>//Nologo //B C:\Microsoft\Windows\Desktop\Initialize.vbs</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
"@ >> dog.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can escape all the quotes so they are passed correctly. Either Control +H - Replace All in notepad, or do a regex to -replace '"','`"' adding a backtick in front of each quote sign.

```
echo "<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"UTF-16`"?>
<Task version=`"1.2`" xmlns=`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task`">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-10-09T14:28:16</Date>
    <Author>$userName</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>


    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT2M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2014-10-09T14:28:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id=`"Author`">
      <UserId>$compName\$userName</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context=`"Author`">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>//Nologo //B C:\Microsoft\Windows\Desktop\Initialize.vbs</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>" >> c:\dog.xml
```